# Does Kafka Batching work with blocking send?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, batching

Considering that the producer.send() method returns a Future, does doing a future.get() right after it block the batching of records as well ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It blocks to flush the buffer of records and wait for any configured ack of the producer.

`KafkaProducer` is thread safe, so calling `send` in a non blocked thread should work, but may result in out-of-order events.

Otherwise, yes, you can call send as many times as needed to batch up data, and not get the first Future.